# Date time exception in coldfusion query in cfc and mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, cfc

I'm moving from an MS Access backend to mySQL. This used to work but now doesn't and I can't figure the problem.

```
<cfargument required="false" name="expiry" type="any" default="" />


        <cfquery datasource='#arguments.dsn#'>      
            INSERT INTO users(expiry)
            VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#arguments.expiry#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP"/>)
        </cfquery>
```

The database field is set to datetime and default NULL

The argument is populated from a form field which is either empty, or a javascript validated date. It chokes on empty formfield.

Comment: The cause of this output exception was that: coldfusion.runtime.locale.CFLocaleBase$InvalidDateTimeException: on is an invalid date or time string..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you mess with the DSN settings, I would also try changing your `<cfqueryparam>` to the following:

```
<cfqueryparam value="#arguments.expiry#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" null="#len(arguments.expiry) eq 0#" />
```

This will pass a true null in the event that the argument value is an empty string.

Comment: This sorted me out Adam, ty, problem was mySQL not put a zero length string as a null, Access has no such qualms !!

Answer (score 1):

CF's implementation of the JDBC driver for MySQL doesn't handle NULL dates very well.

You need to add a config flag to your DSN connection string settings (under advanced) in the CF admin

**&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull**

Should set you right.

Rob